# Why curl charset don't change ?

Tags: php, http, curl, simple-html-dom

I need to parse with simpl_html_dom german site.I have a  problem with  german Umlauts, because utf-8 don't support  Umlauts. I know ,if convert text from UTF-8 to UTF-16 or ISO-8859-1 problem solved.I use CURL for get  content page. This page have charset  ISO-8859-1.I try to set CURLOPT_ENCODING ISO-8859-1 ,but Curl always return the  utf-8 text.I don't  know what do.
   Code of this method.

```
public function testsec()
{
    require_once DIR_SYSTEM.'library'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'simpleHtml'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'simple_html_dom.php';
    $regexpSecond = "~Möglicherweise.*? Vielen Dank~su";        
    $headers = array(
        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0",
        "Accept: text/plain",
        "Connection: keep-alive",
    );

    $fp  = fopen(DIR_ADMIN.'logCurl.txt','w+');
    $head = fopen(DIR_ADMIN.'headers.txt','w+');
    $curl = curl_init("http://test.site.com/bla-bla-bla");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "UTF-16");        
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER ,$headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, $head);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    fclose($fp);
    fclose($head);
    $html = str_get_html($result);
    echo mb_detect_encoding($result); //utf-8

}
```

Headers response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 03 Jul 2016 05:22:34 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: JTLSHOP=c1qv3vafghmf3ih43g5m96epi4; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=1, private, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: That's not what CURLOPT_ENCODING is for, it's not for charset encodings it's for gzip. If the response header says it's iso-8859-1, then it's probably iso-8859-1 but you never posted the url so we can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 support Umlauts.

http://www.periodni.com/unicode_utf-8_encoding.html#german_special_characters

If you want to convert charset, Use [ICONV](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function.